# How do I get the price of product in the base currency?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, magento2.1.5, currency-rates

I have a block on Magento where I would like to display the price of the current product in the default display currency. This store has multiple currencies.

When I invoke `$product->getPrice()`, I get the price of the product converted into the current currency. I can convert this into the the default display currency using this method:

```
public function convertToBaseCurrency(StoreInterface $store, $amount)
{
    $rateToBase = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($store->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getAnyRate($store->getDefaultCurrencyCode());
    return $amount * $rateToBase;
}
```

The above sort-of works but leads to rounding and calculation discrepancies.

I have a product that is **22.00 EUR** in the database. When viewing the product under CHF, I get a price of **23.50 CHF**. The multiplier in the `directory_currency_rate` table for EUR > CHF is **1.068200000000**, which means the product's price should be **23.5004** but somehow it gets rounded down. This basically means that I cannot convert back the price back to EUR wihout some minor discrepancies. I've vardumped the product and it indeed is **23.5** internally.

Having dug in deeper, I can see that the conversion happens and gets rounded. There's a constant that defines the rounding in `PriceCurrencyInterface` called `DEFAULT_PRECISION`

How should I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you should try to avoid writing your own method to convert the prices.

Stick to the following methods defined in `Magento\Directory\Model\Currency`:

- `convert($price, $toCurrency)`
- `format($price, $options = [], $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)`

The first one converts a price to a currency (which is pretty much what you're doing in your custom method).

The second one formats the price by adding the rounding, the currency symbol and also the `<span>` container if you need it. You can change the precision by changing the second parameter to something like: `$options['precision'] = 3`